# Trying to create a class for a simple ball bounce experiment, where am I going wrong?

Tags: c++, class, sfml

I am very new to programming in c++, and I'm trying to create a simple program using SFML in which it is possible to create balls which will bounce around. However I've gotten stuck before I even got to the physics sim. I can't seem to get my ball class working. I wanted to use it to store variables for each ball created and update and draw functions. But every time I end up with some sort of error and I can't find any help on something which is apparently so simple.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <SFML\Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML\Network.hpp>
#include <SFML\System.hpp>
#include <SFML\Window.hpp>


class Ball
{
public:

    // vector for position
    sf::Vector2 pos(100,100);

    // vector for velocity
    sf::Vector2 vel(0,0);

    void update()
    {
        // factors influence velocity
        // update position based on velocity
        pos.x += vel.x;
        pos.y += vel.y;
    }

    void draw()
    {
        // draw ball to the window using position vector
        sf::circleShape circle(10);
        circle.setPosition(pos.x,pos.y);
        circle.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
        window.draw(circle);
    }
};

int main()
{
    /*create window settings*/
    sf::ContextSettings settings;
    settings.antialiasingLevel = 8; // set the antialiasing level

    /*create window*/
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Simple Physics", sf::Style::Default, settings);

    /*create ball(s)*/
    Ball ball01;

    /*Main loop*/
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::White);

        // call ball.update(); and ball.draw();
        ball01.update();
        ball01.draw();

        window.display();
    }
}
```

Any help or crit would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I would encourage you to be very specific; _what_ do you want `Ball` to do and what have you tried to achieve this? _How_ should `Ball` update and render and what have you come up with?

Comment: But to get the ball rolling, so to speak, you can take a look at sfml's `sf::Vector2f` to store position and velocity, and note that `Ball::draw()` will need access to `window` in order to do any drawing. You can also consider using a `std::vector<Ball>` to store many balls, each of which you'd need to update and draw.

Comment: Hi, I just updated to one of the previous things I tried, I understand most of it is probably wrong, but I can't work out from the errors I receive :/

How would I go about giving the draw function access to the window?

Comment: You're referencing `main`'s `window` object, which is certainly not in scope inside `Ball::draw()`. Consider changing the function's signature to `Ball::draw(sf::RenderWindow& window);` and then passing `window` in from `main`

Comment: I understand, would it be `void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window)` instead of the `void draw()` ? Thanks very much for helping by the way!

Comment: Yes, that's right. About the downvotes, Stackoverflow generally prefers specific questions that can help many users in the future, over broad questions that do the asker's work for them.

Comment: Ok, I see, I will make sure to be more specific in the future.

Comment: If you are getting errors it's usually a good idea to include them in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet:

1) Your background color should be different from the ball color.

2) Use window.setFramerateLimit() to slow down animation.

3) Use boundary condition so that the ball do not go out of view .

4) Draw() needs correction as well

```
class Ball
{
public:

    // vector for position
    sf::Vector2f pos{ 100, 100 };

    // vector for velocity
    sf::Vector2f vel{ 1, 1 };

    void update()
    {
        // factors influence velocity
        // update position based on velocity
        pos.x += vel.x;
        pos.y += vel.y;

        if (pos.x > 800 || pos.x < 0) vel.x = -vel.x; //boundary cond
        if (pos.y > 600 || pos.y < 0) vel.y = -vel.y; //boundary cond
    }

    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window)
    {
        // draw ball to the window using position vector 
        sf::CircleShape circle(10);
        circle.setPosition(pos.x, pos.y);
        circle.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);

        window.draw(circle);
    }
};

int main()
{
    /*create window settings*/
    sf::ContextSettings settings;
    settings.antialiasingLevel = 8; // set the antialiasing level

                                    /*create window*/
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Simple Physics", sf::Style::Default, settings);

    /*create ball(s)*/
    Ball ball01;

    window.setFramerateLimit(60); //slow down speed
    /*Main loop*/
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::Black); // ball is white so make backgnd black

        // call ball.update(); and ball.draw();
        ball01.update();
        ball01.draw(window);
        window.display();
    }
}
```